# Set rabbitMQ default guest password to something else

Tags: rabbitmq

I am looking to change rabbitMQ default guest user password to something then guest and guest..........

Config look like this:

```
    [ { rabbit, [
    { loopback_users, [ ] },
    { vm_memory_high_watermark, {absolute, 595276595 }},
    { default_user,  'guest' },
    { default_password, 'somepassword' },
    { disk_free_limit, 52428800 }
] } ].
```

For some reason, the web interface still accessible via guest guest... It does not seem to apply config.

U syspect loopback_users has something to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions or reporting issues about RabbitMQ, please always include the version of RabbitMQ and Erlang you are using.

You must use the correct setting name (`default_pass`) and correct value format:

```
[
    {rabbit, [
        {loopback_users, []},
        {vm_memory_high_watermark, {absolute, 595276595}},
        {default_user, <<"guest">>},
        {default_pass, <<"somepassword">>},
        {disk_free_limit, 52428800}
    ]}
].
```

The above are documented [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.7.17/docs/rabbitmq.config.example#L166-L185).

Also, if you have started RabbitMQ prior to using this configuration, the `guest` user will already have been created using `guest` as the password. The `default_user` and `default_pass` settings *only* apply to fresh nodes.

If you are using RabbitMQ 3.7.X, you should investigate the `.conf` INI-style configuration format instead, as it is friendlier:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.7.17/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example

---

<sub>**NOTE:** the RabbitMQ team monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.</sub>

Comment: The version is 3.6.X. That said, even with the {default_user, <<"guest">>} markup, guest still use the password guest and not the overwritten <<"somepassword">> .

Comment: I tested with version 3.7.17 as 3.6.X is no longer supported. Did you see the part where these settings _only_ apply to the first start of a node? If this is a development environment, remove the `/var/lib/rabbitmq` directory and re-start to have the settings applied.

Comment: I am planning to test on Tuesday 27. Will keep this post updated as soon this is done.

Comment: I did update my config with ''clean storage'' and it did the job. So I guess this is it. Next step is to configure more than 1 user with specific privileges and see how it goes. But this is another topic.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up